# WebGL Issue with Texturing (Weird graphical glitches and mapping issue)

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, textures, webgl, blender

My issue is that when using WebGL and attempting to read an OBJ model, the texture mapping is all screwy. Here is what it looks like in Blender.

[image: Blender UV Mapped]

I may be completely off when I say this, but I believe on the right window, that little white circle with red point represents the UV coordinates (0,0) which would mean the other coordinates to the left and/or below contain a negative number in them.

Here is what the output is in WebGL

[image: WebGL Output]

The mapping is completely off (I have tried clamping and repeating to no avail) and there is some strange noise in the middle. So my question is, how can you get correct UV coordinates from Blender which are between 0 and 1 as well as getting rid of the noise in WebGL.

Here is what the texture loading method looks like before the texture is passed to WebGL for rendering in the draw loop

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

**UPDATE**
When NOT keeping vertex order:

[image: Better results]

Comment: Make one face surface and add simple texture map(generate coordinates) then export it to obj and open with text editor.  Here's OBJ file structure http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file Make sure that they are exported correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by making sure that I was grabbing UV coordinates in the form of (s,t) and not (x,y,z). By grabbing individual coordinates by groups of 2 (like I should have been doing) instead of by groups of 3, I was able to get the texture coordinates to map perfectly every time.